# Folders structure created within VS2022 is not visible in the physical folder view

Tags: visual-studio-2022, class-library, .net-7.0

I created a empty blank solution using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.5.5. I added following folder structure :

[image]

In this case I can see the Services and Basket folder in the Visual Studio 2022 but on navigating to the folder view I cannot the Physical folders : Services and Basket

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the solution explorer?